# "No endpoint mapping found" in Soap WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap

I'm trying to create a simple Soap WS using [this tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html). I'm capable of seeing the wsdl generated dynamically via browser but when i try to test it, it gaves me a warning.

HumanResourceService

```
package com.mycompany.hr.service;

import java.util.Date;

public interface HumanResourceService {
    void bookHoliday(Date startDate, Date endDate, String name);
}
```

StubHumanResourceService

```
package com.mycompany.hr.service;

import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service   
public class StubHumanResourceService implements HumanResourceService
{
      public void bookHoliday(Date startDate, Date endDate, String name) {
            System.out.println("Booking holiday for [" + startDate + "-" + endDate + "] for [" + name + "] ");
        }
}
```

HolidayEndpoint

```
package com.mycompany.hr.ws;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;

import com.mycompany.hr.service.HumanResourceService;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.Namespace;
import org.jdom.xpath.XPath;

@Endpoint
public class HolidayEndpoint {

  private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas";

  private XPath startDateExpression;

  private XPath endDateExpression;

  private XPath nameExpression;

  private HumanResourceService humanResourceService;

  @Autowired
  public HolidayEndpoint(HumanResourceService humanResourceService)
      throws JDOMException {
    this.humanResourceService = humanResourceService;

    Namespace namespace = Namespace.getNamespace("hr", NAMESPACE_URI);

    startDateExpression = XPath.newInstance("//hr:StartDate");
    startDateExpression.addNamespace(namespace);

    endDateExpression = XPath.newInstance("//hr:EndDate");
    endDateExpression.addNamespace(namespace);

    nameExpression = XPath.newInstance("concat(//hr:FirstName,' ',//hr:LastName)");
    nameExpression.addNamespace(namespace);
  }

  @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "HolidayRequest")
  public void handleHolidayRequest(@RequestPayload Element holidayRequest)
      throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date startDate = dateFormat.parse(startDateExpression.valueOf(holidayRequest));
    Date endDate = dateFormat.parse(endDateExpression.valueOf(holidayRequest));
    String name = nameExpression.valueOf(holidayRequest);

    humanResourceService.bookHoliday(startDate, endDate, name);
  }

}
```

hr.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:hr="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas">
    <xs:element name="HolidayRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="Holiday" type="hr:HolidayType"/>
                <xs:element name="Employee" type="hr:EmployeeType"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="HolidayType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="EndDate" type="xs:date"/>           
        </xs:sequence>                                            
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/> 
        </xs:sequence>                                     
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-ws-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <sws:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.hr" />

    <sws:dynamic-wsdl id="holiday" 
                        portTypeName="HumanResource"
                        locationUri="/holidayService/" 
                        targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions">
        <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/hr.xsd" />
    </sws:dynamic-wsdl>

</beans>
```

And here the wsdl that I use in SoapUI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:sch="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:hr="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas">
    <xs:element name="HolidayRequest">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="Holiday" type="hr:HolidayType"/>
                <xs:element name="Employee" type="hr:EmployeeType"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="HolidayType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="EndDate" type="xs:date"/>           
        </xs:sequence>                                            
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/> 
        </xs:sequence>                                     
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="HolidayRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="sch:HolidayRequest" name="HolidayRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="HumanResource">
    <wsdl:operation name="Holiday">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:HolidayRequest" name="HolidayRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="HumanResourceSoap11" type="tns:HumanResource">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Holiday">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input name="HolidayRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="HumanResourceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:HumanResourceSoap11" name="HumanResourceSoap11">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/holidayService/holidayService/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I run it, STS gives me the following warning:

> ADVERTENCIA: No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://mycompany.com/hr/schemas}HolidayRequest]

And I can't get any response. I had tried to follow the threads related to my issue but I haven't seen any specific answer.

Thank you very much

Comment: Try adding component scan so that at least it will scan your controller package since you are mapping any request.

Comment: i thought I was doing that on spring-ws-servlet.xml

Comment: But your spring-ws-servlet.xml was not having that code thats why I suggested that.Is that working after making the change?